# Change attribute/getter/setter visibility in abap persistent class

Tags: abap

**Is there a possibility to change the visibility of the setter/getter from an attribute without changing attribute visibility?**

e.g in Java I can say:

- attribute: private
- setter: protected
- getter: public

That is very practic if I want to allow only in private scope changes, in protected scope I allow changes via setter (some checks and verifications in there) and in public scope you can only read.

In the classbuilder you can only change all of them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the attribute public and change it to read-only in the persistence mapping - this will prevent the setter from being generated. You can change the attribute visibility in the class builder or the persistence mapping, which will affect both the setter and the getter. As far as I know, there are no other ways to affect the visibility. For a greater control, I'd recommend wrapping the persistence class - either in a separate class or by introducing a public getter-only interface whose methods defer to the generated getters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just make use of this button.

[image]

And then change the visibility

[image]

Comment: This is a bad idea: Any changes in the persistence mapping will trigger a re-generation of the getters and setters, and this change will be reverted. Other events might trigger that re-generation as well.

Comment: The question was not about whether it is a good or bad idea but how to achieve it but I appreciate your comment anyway.